# Creating 2 versions of homepage in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, multisite

I have a Wordpress site which uses a theme. I wish to another version of the same site in a different language. Is there a way I could use the same Wordpress installation to run the site in the other language as well ?

The site structures are the same, except that the menus and the content are in different language.

I tried to copy the wp-content/themes/theme-name/index.php to german.php but failed to access the german site via /german.

Any guidance here ? I do not want to use automated translation plugins.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [Polylang](https://wordpress.org/plugins/polylang/) plugin. You can add multiple languages and you can create separate page and contents for multiple languages.

Unlike other multilang plugins, polylang create separate posts for different language and does not save the content under same post.

Comment: Thanks. Looks promising. Will give this  a try.

Comment: I've been using this plugin for quite long now, let me know if you have any other queries.

Answer (score 1):

Use a plugin for translations, like: https://wpml.org/

Comment: I do not want to use automated translations, rather want to create a separate page, menus and content myself.

Comment: wpml is not automated, you have to translate the things yourself. But you could use different template files and assign them accordingly to the language you want to use.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will try.

Answer (score 1):

add all the fields you want to translate extra to the home page

Say english is your head lannguage

for "post_content" you make "post_content_de".
etc

to add fields use:

**acf** https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/

or

**wp** https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields

I prefer acf.

Make a check with
$_POST or $_GET or $_SESSION or $_COOKIE

Answer (score 0):

Use qTranslate X wordpress plugin it is easy to use

https://wordpress.org/plugins/qtranslate-x/

Comment: Thanks @vinit. Will try.